# Can devise sign_in() test helper accept a new_record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the following example, can I use `build()` instead of `create()`?

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase  

  setup do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
  end

  test "admin can get index" do
    sign_in @user
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "user cannot get index" do
    sign_in @user
    get :index
    assert_response 403
  end

end
```

In real-life use, the user would have already been created (saved) before signing in, so that's why my test uses `create()`.  However, I want to use `build()` because I hope it will make my tests faster.

The devise [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.rdoc) does not explicitly say that it is OK to use build().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the user record must be persisted, according to this note by José.

> A mock is never going to work. When you say sign in, the user is
>   stored in session (basically, the user class and its id). When you
>   access the controller, another user object is retrieved based on the
>   stored data. The best way to solve the problem is using something that
>   persists the object, like Factory Girl.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/928